# Decimal out of range C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, decimal

I have a C# Entity Framework class like this:

```
public class Card 
{
    public decimal CardNumber { get; set; }
}
```

In the database, this value is stored something like this:

```
[card_number] [decimal](38, 2) NULL
```

Then when I go to run this code:

```
 entities.Set<Card>().Add(card);
 entities.SaveChanges();
```

(It should fail on save changes)

I seem to get this exception:

> Parameter value '2509067194275615035776.00' is out of range.

I tried to insert that value manually in SQL Server Management Studio and it seemed to work ok...

Mind you this was recently changed from a long in C# and a `bigint` in SQL Server to a `decimal` in C# and a `decimal` in SQL Server...

I also have this config class that looks something like this and maps the C# object to the database...

```
public class CardConfiguration : TrackedEntityConfiguration<Card>
{
    public CardConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Card", "dbo");
       
        Property(c => c.CardNumber)
             .HasColumnName("card_number") 
             .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

I don't know why I'm getting this exception as it does not seem bigger than the decimal max value in SQL Server....

I'm a bit new to Entity Framework, so maybe I'm missing some other config somewhere?

Comment: Are you using entity-framework ? or entity-framework core ? if in the first case (if your question tagging is correct) are you using an edmx to map classes to your database ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the decimal's precision.  For example:

```cs
Property(c => c.CardNumber).HasColumnName("card_number").HasPrecision(18, 6);
```

precision depends on your SQL Column definition.  See column properties dialog:
[image: Numeric precision in SQL Properties dialog]

Comment: Because if you don't specify precision and scale, you'll get `decimal(38,0)` in SQL Server - **no** digits after the decimal point! That's what's causing the "out of range" error ....